# In a mySQL result, how can I access a field value to choose the variable based on the other field value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok I know the title probably sound confusing which is also why I couldnt find an answer for it.

Say I get this table as a result from a mysqli query in php

```
Year| Count
------
1 | 7
2 | 4
3 | 9
```

And say I knew that the possible options in Year woud be 1 2 or 3 only.

From that result I want to set this code, but am unsure how best to do it

```
$Year1 = 7
$Year2 = 4
$Year3 = 9
```

Comment: Instead of $Year1, $Year2, $Year3, you should consider using an array ($Years = [7, 4, 9]; echo $Years[0].'-'$Years[1].'-'.$Years[2]).
And to answer your question completely, I need your php code to see how you receive data from MySQL.

Comment: provide your php code fragment. Quick response: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) ${'Year'.$row['year']} = $row['count'];`

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach.. why not create an indexed array based on the year?

```
// perform your sql
$years = array(); // or $years = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $years[$row['year']] = $row['count'];
}
print_r($years);
```

Couple of advantages of this approach..

- You know how many years you're dealing with `count($years)`
- You can loop over them easily with `foreach`
- you can get all the years with `array_keys($years)`
- You can get all the counts with `array_values($years)`
- You can get the total count with `array_sum($years)`

<del>(I love arrays)</del>

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Year{$row['year']} = $row['count'];
}
```

You can then loop on the total count of records and print them as well

```
 if(!empty($Year1){
   echo $Year1;
 }
```

Here is how we use curly brackets in php:

```
<?php

$a = '12345';

// This works:
echo "qwe{$a}rty"; // qwe12345rty, using braces
echo "qwe" . $a . "rty"; // qwe12345rty, concatenation used

// Does not work:
 echo 'qwe{$a}rty'; // qwe{$a}rty, single quotes are not parsed
echo "qwe$arty"; // qwe, because $a became $arty, which is undefined

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can connect and query. 
**I am only doing it this way to show how to use individual variables as asked for in the question.** I would highly suggest using an array as @Dale has.

```
$count = 1;
//Define all your variables here
//I set to -1 for checking in the future
//Assuming all counts would be positive.
$Year1 = -1;
$Year2 = -1;
$Year3 = -1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    switch($count){
        case 1:
            $Year1 = $row['count'];
            $count++;
            break;
        case 2:
            $Year2 = $row['count'];
            $count++;
            break;
        case 3:
            $Year3 = $row['count'];
            $count++;
            break;
        //and so on...you can see this is awful right?
        default:
            //Something if the case does not exist.
    }
}
```